# How do I move /boot to a separate partition on UEFI system with current boot on btrfs?

Tags: boot, uefi, btrfs, boot-partition

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a UEFI system with `/boot` on a btrfs partition (subvol=@).

Because of recent changes in Ubuntu I always get grub timeout 30 sec. This is by design if `/boot` is on a btrfs partition.

Part of `/grub.cfg`

```sh
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  # GRUB lacks write support for btrfs, so recordfail support is disabled.
}
...
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
```

I think that if I create a separate ext2 `/boot` partition the problem will be solved.

The question is if the above assumption is correct, how do I move `boot` from a btrfs subvol to an ext2 partition?

Comment: Not really different than moving /home to new partition. Create partition, copy /boot files, edit fstab, but you will have to reinstall grub so it searches for new location. Because you need to reinstall grub anyway, you can create partition & edit fstab. Then in Boot-Repair's advanced mode do the full reinstall of grub & new kernel options. Full reinstall of grub will reset any changes you made to grub configuration, so save those or know what you normally change.

Comment: I tried to do it without using Boot-repair and can't figure that out. Do I mount `boot/efi` partition ,etc. Maybe Boot-repair is an option.

Comment: You must be sure to boot in same boot mode, UEFI or BIOS, so reinstall is correct. Boot-Repair will see in fstab, the ESP & /boot partitions, so they must be in fstab first.

Comment: Alternatively you could set grub's timeout with a single line `set timeout=x` in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, `chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom`, `sudo update-grub` to your desired timeout. The snippet you show is from `/etc/grub.d/00_header` which is processed first when creating `grub.cfg`, setting the timeout  later again will then take precedence.

Comment: It looks like boot-repair fixed it. But it checks `/boot`/ every time.

Comment: Here we have `btrfs` specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it using Boot-repair from a LiveUSB.

Before start I recommend to create a snapshot of `@` subvolume in case something goes wrong.

1. Shrink `/` partition to leave 1-2 GB free with `gparted`
2. Create `ext2` partition.
3. Mount the `/` partition to `/mnt`
4. Mount the new `ext2` partition to `/media`
5. Run `cp -a /mnt/@/boot/* /media`
6. Edit `/mnt/@/etc/fstab` and add there mount of the new `ext2` partition to `/boot`.
7. Delete old boot from `/` by `sudo rm -r /mnt/@/boot`
8. Run `sudo umount /mnt && sudo umount /media`
9. Run `boot-repair` and do a default check.

All should work, and grub timeout is OK now.

Comment: Congrats on the bounty!  **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to fix timeout issue on btrfs file systems.

You can add

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`.

But make sure you can always get into UEFI settings using ESC or other key.